# Fluentd parsing nginx access log doesn't work

Tags: nginx, logging, fluentd

I want to parse nginx access logs and provide the data to prometheus. The problem is, fluentd (or rather td-agent) doesn't want to match my regex. The example is straight from [docs](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/nginx), but modified with prometheus output:

```
# source nginx access logs
<source>
        @type tail
        path /var/log/nginx/access.log
        pos_file /var/log/fluentd.pos
        tag nginx.access

        <parse>
                @type nginx
                expression /^(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?: +\S*)?)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)"(?:\s+(?<http_x_forwarded_for>[^ ]+))?)?$/
                time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
        </parse>
        read_from_head true
        @log_level debug
</source>

<source>
        @type prometheus
        bind 0.0.0.0
        port 9009
        metrics_path /metrics
</source>

<filter nginx.access>
        @type prometheus
        <labels>
                remote ${remote}
                method ${method}
                path ${path}
                code ${code}
                size ${size}
                agent ${agent}
        </labels>
        <metric>
                name status
                type counter
                desc status code
                key status
        </metric>
</filter>
```

When I run this config and access some page that creates an nginx log, it just prints out

```
 [warn]: #0 no patterns matched tag="nginx.access"
```

and for love of god I cannot figure out why is this happening. If I remove the time format line, it crashes because it has found invalid time string, so it at least matches the string. But when I add that, it just crashes. I've tried not using it, changing `@type nginx` to `@type regexp`. Fluentular parses the test string with this exact same settings without a problem, so I have no clue where the problem is.

Example data:

```
192.168.1.1 - - [07/Jun/2023:20:32:55 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3275 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0"
192.168.1.1 - - [07/Jun/2023:20:32:56 +0200] "GET /cockpit/login HTTP/1.1" 401 3464 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0"
192.168.1.1 - - [07/Jun/2023:20:32:56 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3275 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0"
192.168.1.1 - - [07/Jun/2023:20:32:56 +0200] "GET /cockpit/login HTTP/1.1" 401 3464 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0"
192.168.1.1 - - [07/Jun/2023:20:32:56 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3275 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0"
192.168.1.1 - - [07/Jun/2023:20:32:56 +0200] "GET /cockpit/login HTTP/1.1" 401 3464 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0"
192.168.1.1 - - [07/Jun/2023:20:33:27 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3275 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0"
```

Comment: For [nginx](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/nginx) parser plugin, you don't have to specify `expression` or `time_format` as it's [handled internally](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/blob/master/lib/fluent/plugin/parser_nginx.rb). You might be getting warnings for unused parameters in the fluentd startup logs.

Comment: The `source` section for `prometheus` looks redundant in your config. What do you mean by "**modified with prometheus output**"? If by that, you mean the logs are custom and not follow the exact pattern, you should be using [`regexp`](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/regexp) parser plugin instead to accommodate your custom format.

Comment: @Azeem I know that they are handled internally, but that does produce the exact same result. It doesn't say anything about unused parameters at the startup however.
And by "modified with prometeus output" I meant that I just pass it on to prometheus. Nginx logs are default ones, they are not modified. However none of this is related to the fact, that the nginx log parsing is not working.

Comment: Is that your complete config?

Comment: I just tested your logs with `tail` using `nginx` parser's defaults with `stdout` and it's working fine.

Comment: Yes, that is the complete config. Tested it with stdout too, it is working. Which kind of bums me, because no matter what I do, it just doesn't want to match with setup above.

Comment: Your above config doesn't have any `match` section with tag `nginx.access`. How are you going to use it then?

Comment: I just verified that without any `match` section, it does omit the same warning `2023-06-08 18:24:55 +0500 [warn]: #0 no patterns matched tag="nginx.access"`. The warning for an unmatched regex is different i.e. `2023-06-08 18:26:44 +0500 [warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "...event..."`.

Comment: Oh my god you're totally right lol, I've added the match section and some other parts, they are most likely redundant but it works. Of course it has just occured to me, that "no patterns matched" __doesn't__ mean "matched [regex]" but "matched [output plugin]". Very well, I have now data in Prometheus, time to move on and learn how to process data there. Thank you, you can post this as an solution.

Comment: Good to hear that. Voting it to closing as it was caused by a typo. There must be an answer for this on SO. It didn't come to me right away until I tested it on my side. Well, it's fixed now. Cheers!